SwiftUI: ViewModifier doesn't update when character limit is changed dynamically from outside
I am working on a SwiftUI project where I need to limit the number of characters a user can input in a TextField. I have implemented a custom ViewModifier to enforce this character limit. The limit is passed from outside the view (e.g., from a parent view), and the TextField should dynamically adjust when this limit changes.
However, while everything works as expected the first time ( with the first characterLimit), it doesn't when the characterLimit is updated.
the characterLimit in the modifier stays the same as it was initially.
Here’s the code for my custom ViewModifier:
import SwiftUI

struct LimitCharactersModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var text: String
    var limit: Int

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                trimTextIfNeeded()
            }
            .onChange(of: limit) { newLimit in
                trimTextIfNeeded()
            }
    }

    private func trimTextIfNeeded() {
        if text.count > limit {
            text = String(text.prefix(limit))
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func limitCharacters(text: Binding<String>, to limit: Int) -> some View {
        self.modifier(LimitCharactersModifier(text: text, limit: limit))
    }
}

Here’s how I am using it in my ContentView:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var characterLimit: Int  // Limit is passed in from outside

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
                .limitCharacters(text: $text, to: characterLimit)
                .padding()
                .border(Color.gray)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

Issue:
although the modifier responding to characterLimit changes, the value does't seems to be updated and stays the same.
Question:
Why the ViewModifier responding to the external changes but doesn't use the updated characterLimit values?
Any guidance or suggestions for a better approach would be appreciated!

So far I don’t see anything that tells SwiftUI to reload.

onChange is for external actions, for transforming edits you can use computed bindings

@malhal thats a nice "input" (;
but I feel like the modifier is nicer looking, i.e. It prevents me from writing the trim logic again and again on  every TextField i use. the modifier helps me with reusability. unless there is something else to benefit using computed bindings, that I am missing

@vigdora you asked for suggestion for better approach so that's what I gave you ;-) It is worth learning how to do data flow and transformation in SwiftUI correctly, .onChange and ViewModifier are not right. ViewModifier isn't designed for data flow its job is to group a bunch of view modifiers together into one reusable modifier that can be applied to any View. And .onChange is for external actions not for transforming data. There are ways to make trim logic reusable in a data flow just need to learn it.

@malhal while I can relate to your comment about ViewModifier in general, I still dont understand what do you mean by external changes vs transforming data

An example of an external action is  logging to file

@malhal ok, so responses from external APIs etc.. I get it, but what is wrong with using onChange() for other staff (line keyboard input etc..). I understand there is a convention, but what the reasoning behind it?

The main reasoning is it is more efficient, i.e. in your code body is called 3x more than if the data flow was correct.

Question: Why the ViewModifier responding to the external changes but doesn't use the updated characterLimit values?
Answer: When you say that the ViewModifier responds to external changes, I assume it responds to the text provided from the outside. If so, be aware that it responds because the outside text is provided as a Binding.
The reason it doesn't use the (outside) updated character limit is because the characterLimit is NOT provided as a Binding, but as a var - and a var of type Int or String (or even a struct) is a value type. Value types are passed by value, meaning they are copied when passed to functions or assigned to other variables.
Note, though, that it is the var type (in this case Int) and not the use of a var that determines whether it's a value type or a reference type.
This is because you can have a var that holds an object which is an instance of a class, which would make that var a reference type:
var characterLimit: Int //value type

var someOtherLimit: MyLimitClass //reference type 

var specialLimit: CustomLimit = CustomLimit() //reference type

A @Binding on the other hand is a reference to the state in the parent view, allowing the respective var to observe and update the value in both child view and parent/root view.
If you need further insight into this, I suggest Apple's state and data flow tutorial.
Here's the complete code with the necessary changes to support what you may be looking for and some minor restructuring explained below:
struct LimitCharactersRootView: View {
    
    @State private var textFieldText = "Some longer filler text that will be trimmed..."
    @State private var characterLimit = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section("Root View"){
                //convenience textfield for controlling the length of text passed to child view textfield
                TextField("Original text", text: $textFieldText)
                
                //convenience stepper for adjusting the character limit for testing
                Stepper("Character limit: \(characterLimit)", value: $characterLimit, in: 5...50 )
                
            }
            Section("Child View") {
                LimitCharactersView(text: $textFieldText, characterLimit:  $characterLimit)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LimitCharactersView: View {
    
    @Binding var text: String //Text is passed in from outside
    @Binding var characterLimit: Int  // Limit is passed in from outside

    @State private var inputText: String = "" //local state for text field
    @State private var showLimitNotice = false //local state that show/hides the textfield character limit reached notice

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Section {
                TextField("Enter text", text: $inputText)
                    .limitCharacters(inputText: $inputText, to: characterLimit, originalText: $text, showNotice: $showLimitNotice)
                    .padding()
                    .border(Color.gray)
            } header: {
                
            } footer: {
                if showLimitNotice {
                    Text("* Character limit has been reached")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                }
            }
            
            //convenience button for testing purposes
            Button("Reset to original text"){
                inputText = text
            }
            .padding(.top)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    
    func limitCharacters(inputText: Binding<String>, to limit: Int, originalText: Binding<String>, showNotice: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        
        let input = inputText.wrappedValue //for convenience
        
        //computed property that holds the trimmed input text
        var trimmedText: String {
            input.count > limit ? String(input.prefix(limit)) : input
        }
        
        //computed property that determines if the text reached the character limit
        var notice: Bool {
            trimmedText.count == limit ? true : false
        }
        
        //helper computed property/closure to avoid typing the same lines in multiple places
        var update: () {
            inputText.wrappedValue = trimmedText
            showNotice.wrappedValue = notice
        }
        
        return self
        
            //when view initially loads, load the outside text into the textfield
            .onAppear {
                inputText.wrappedValue = originalText.wrappedValue
            }
        
            //if outside limit changes, limit if needed based on character limit
            .onChange(of: limit) {
                update
            }
        
            //if textfield text changes, limit if needed based on character limit
            .onChange(of: input) {
                update
            }   
        
            //if original text changes, update the textfield (optional, based on use case)
            .onChange(of: originalText.wrappedValue) {
                inputText.wrappedValue = originalText.wrappedValue
            }
    }
}

#Preview("Limit characters"){
    LimitCharactersRootView()
}

Some insight:

For the ViewModifier to respond to outside updated characterLimit, the characterLimit is defined as a state in LimitCharactersRootView and passed as a Binding to LimitCharactersView (child view).

I changed the approach slightly by eliminating the LimitCharactersModifier ViewModifier struct to show you that it is NOT required to achieve what you need. You can do the needed trimming inside the View extension function limitCharacters(..), and thus avoid unnecessary code bloat.

For convenience and demo/testing purposes, the field shows a notice indicating the character limit was reached.

I do not know your entire use case and why the text is provided from outside, so the demo includes a textfield in root view to control the length of the text (for testing).



thanks! there are two things that still confuse me though: when I took the two .onChanges methods out of the modifier and put them directly on the TextField it worked perfectly.
also when I put a break point inside the onChange(of: limit) it was indeed triggered, but with the old value! (although the breakpoint inside the limitCharacters() was the new one)
so your example works. but I still don't understand everything

Hard to say why the modifiers work directly on the TextField since your provided code does not include the parent view that provides the values and what you describe is not reproducible in that regard. But it would make sense for it not to work as expected if your view doesn't update accordingly based on changed values in the parent view. You can attempt to troubleshoot by printing the values in question at different points: like before calling childview, onAppear of childView, onAppear of the viewmodifier, etc., and see if they match.

I forgot to mention in my answer that the way you're using .onChange is deprecated. The current way is to either call it without { newValue in in the closure or with two parameters {oldValue, newValue in. Check the documentation for more details. By updating to the new onChange format, you will also be able to compare old and new values.

Andrei, when you use extension instead of modifier: dont you compromise on efficiency with those computer vars - as they will run on each re-render?

I can't say I ever considered that so far, as I didn't have a need to optimize due to any performance bottlenecks. If a ViewModifier was used, wouldn't that be called anyway by the extension function on each re-render? For me, given the context of a non-resource intensive app, the convenience of not having to use a viewmodifier struct if not needed outweighs any negligible potential inefficiency. But I'll look into it and update here as needed.

in the  ViewModifier, the "onChanged" is triggered only when the corresponding variable changes. but with the extension, no matter what triggers the re-rendering, the computational vars will run each time (I agree it is just a nuance). I also wondering why @malhal, who commented on my original post is so against modifiers in this context... Andrei, thanks for you insights regardless
